# I have not heard from you lately / for a long time

Tags: phrase-choice, formality

> I have not heard from you lately.
>
> Regards,
>   ABC

Is it formal to write "I have not heard from you lately," or it is better to write "I have not heard from you for a long time"?

Answer (score 3):

Both are good enough and better than "haven't" in a formal correspondence. The choice between the two sentences depends on how long the duration since the last correspondence is perceived to be.

Depending on the usual frequency of correspondence, and the relationship between the two parties (you mentioned it was formal, but I think it's helpful to go broader for those who are curious about the general use):

"Lately" can mean anything between a few days and a few months. "A long time" can be 4 years between two e-mail penpals who only exchange emails once a year, or five days between two lovers who live away from each other but try to keep in touch at least once every two days.

Normally, "A long time" would imply a longer duration than "lately".

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. I'd probably understand "for a long time" to mean more time than "lately". But just how long either one means depends on context.

BTW you should say "replying to an email" (someone else sent me an email and I am now replying, probably but not necessarily with an email) or "replying with an email" (I am sending an email in response to a message from someone else, which might or might not have been an email). You need a preposition: you can't say just "replying an email".